# Close Screen Flow Modal On Clicking The Hyperlink

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow

We have a requirement in which we need to close the screen flow modal on click of a hyperlink. We have 2 flows. First screen flow is invoking the second one on the basis of a criteria. In one of the step of child flow, we have a screen asking user to
"Click here to Cancel", on click of which the modal should close and user should remain on the respective record page, without refreshing it as there have been no changes to any of the field values.

Comment: First, consider using sub-flows to allow the one flow to call the other. Second, remove the "Click here to cancel" and replace with a message saying "Click the X button for this dialog to cancel"...